# FB feed dialogue accepts "ref" param, but does not attach it to newsfeed item

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, feed

Facebook's Javascript SDK implements the FB.ui method which allows one to programatically launch dialogues. The "feed" dialogue accepts the "ref" parameter but does not append it as the "fb_ref" query param on the news feed link it creates which is the default behavior of the "ref" param in many other instances. Here's example usage:

```
<script>
    var publish = {
      method: 'feed',
      message: 'getting educated about Facebook Connect',
      name: 'Connect',
      caption: 'The Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK',
      description: (
          'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
          'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
          'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
      ),
      link: 'http://www.fbrell.com/?ref=poo',
      picture: 'http://www.fbrell.com/public/f8.jpg',
      ref:'foo',
      actions: [
        { name: 'fbrell', link: 'http://www.fbrell.com/' }
      ],
      user_message_prompt: 'Share your thoughts about RELL'
    };

    FB.ui(publish, Log.info.bind('feed callback'));
    </script>
```

The documentation of the "Feed Dialogue" states that the "ref" param is

> A text reference for the category of feed post. This category is used
>   in Facebook Insights to help you measure the performance of different
>   types of post

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

It does not claim to append it to the newsfeed link. However, on a separate piece of documentation for "Feed Gaming" which uses the feed dialogue, it states this about the "ref" param:

> This value will also be passed back to you in the fb_ref parameter
>   which will be appended onto the end of the url when users click on
>   your story title and are taken directly to the game - i.e. without
>   playing the embedded content.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/feed-gaming/

Feed Gaming is utilizing the FB.ui "feed" dialogue so it appears that this documentation is contradictory or at least not normalized.  Does anyone know how to get the "feed" dialogue to append the ref param to the end of news story urls?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can read from the documentation, you define the **ref** value to

> measure the performance of different types of post

and such value will be passed

> back to you in the **fb_ref** parameter which will be appended onto the end of the url.

Thus, your game will recieve the value that you defined in the **ref** in the **fb_ref** query param.

Comment: I referred to the ref and fb_ref parameter throughout my question. While it works for likes, it does not work for feed posts which is the thrust of my question.